# how to see linux command exec time by each user

Tags: linux

I want to see  **who exec what commands and when was executed** .
History command only log the command , which with timestamp.
What I've check is man (3) history , I can see :

```
typedef void * histdata_t;

   typedef struct _hist_entry {
     char *line;
     char *timestamp;
     histdata_t data;
   } HIST_ENTRY;
```

is this means there is a way to see command exectue time?

Also I found others also looking for some similar solution:

[Linux history of all commands executed during whole day, everyday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912751/linux-history-of-all-commands-executed-during-whole-day-everyday)

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/recording-all-the-command-history-in-a-log-4175484336/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279040/is-there-a-way-to-get-user-executed-commands-using-linux-c

they were looking solution to record time .
But what I seeking is command exec time by which user **in the past time** , not in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the history command, you can enable timestamps like so:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T  '
```

Then when you call history, timestamps are enabled.

Example:

```
 1754  2014-07-10 10:12:24  sed -i '0,/port \([0-9]*\)/{s/port \([0-9]*\)/port 7777/}' test.txt
 1755  2014-07-10 10:12:26  cat test.txt
 1756  2014-07-10 10:16:54  export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T  '
 1757  2014-07-10 10:16:55  history
 me@owncloud:~$
```

Comment: thanks @wbt11a . this solve my problem. But I have a more question:history only list out some recent command , I was able to see command server days ago:$ history
  997  2014-07-11 10:50:58  df -h    which is before 997. Can I track more?

Comment: , But   all the command is record as the same time    in the past. 1984  2014-07-11 10:50:58  varnishlog 
 1985  2014-07-11 10:50:58  ps -ef | grep redis
 1986  2014-07-11 10:50:58  vim /etc/redis/6380.conf
 1987  2014-07-11 10:50:58  redis-cli. all is at 10:50:58